# Software protection and license management

Tags: .net, licensing, license-key

I have following requirements for selecting a license product for my software

1. .Net based
2. License manager - Should be able to view and manage the customers interactively, automatically,e-commerce is not mandatory.
3. Good Customer support, examples and available source codes
4. I may need to update the license monthly and exciting users should be able to get those
   from license server automatically (mandatory requirement, we control the customers like this)
5. And Most importantly the price for my requirements

Based on these requirements I have following options

1. Software Key (http://www.softwarekey.com/protection-plus/5/)
2. CryptoLicensing For .Net(http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/features_net.htm)
3. EZIRIZ(http://www.eziriz.com/)
4. LicenseSpot (http://www.licensespot.com/)
5. Eleckey 2.0 Internet Plus (http://www.sciensoft.com/products/eleckey/comparison.html)

Do you have any views or any more suggestions on this? What would you suggest?

Edit

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272184/good-commercial-third-party-tool-for-software-licensing)  for CryptoLicensing , [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272184/good-commercial-third-party-tool-for-software-licensing) for Eleckey 2.0 and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423889/has-anybody-used-manco-net-licensing-for-net) for manco.net. Any comments for other products?

Comment: Good job performing research! Unfortunately it's still a "shopping / external recommendation question" and I do not think it's a good fit for SO.

Comment: My question is something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035757/good-or-bad-experiences-with-cryptolicensing

Comment: @user2864740 For someone who has 8.5k rep why do you still have a generic username like that?

Comment: https://wyday.com/limelm/ is another one to add to your shopping list

Comment: To extend the list of products further, I would recommend https://cryptolens.io/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my requirement (hosted web server) and experience,there are two choices. one is Software Key and the other one is LicenseSpot. Both have their own advantages. Software Key is feature rich and instant customer support. LicenseSpot is simple and price also less

Answer (score 17):

One of my favorite licensing system is [Portable.Licensing](http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/portable-licensing). It's very flexible, portable due to the PCL and has a powerful but easy to learn fluent API. I've used it successfully in many applications. My own and other business applications.

Maybe this is a good alternative.

If you need further help, there's also a Pluralsight course about "[Licensing .NET Applications](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/licensing-dotnet-applications)" that features Portable.Licensing (I'm the author of the video).

Cheers

Comment: Yes, It would be one solution, but their License manager is still a lite version, unless I would have chosen that

Comment: @Robin: there is also a web based license manager https://github.com/dnauck/License.Manager ... its only missing a user management

Comment: @dna, Yes Actually I need that functionality. May be in future

Comment: This is a pretty awesome solution! I really like how elegant and simple it is.